# Find $E=\tanh(D)$ where $D=\left\{z \in \mathbb C\mid\frac{-\pi}{2}<\Im(z)<\frac{\pi}{2} \right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Consider $$f(z)=\frac{e^{2z} - 1}{e^{2z} +1}=\tanh(z)$$

Find $E=f(D)$

Let $Z=e^{2z}$, $Z$ mapping $D$ into $\mathbb{C}\smallsetminus]-\infty , 0 ]$

since $$\rho e^{i\phi}=e^{2x}.e^{2iy} \Rightarrow \rho=e^2x \  , -\pi<\phi<\pi$$

and then we need to find the mapping of $\mathbb{C\smallsetminus]-\infty,0]}$ under  $\frac{Z-1}{Z+1}$

$$w=\frac{Z-1}{Z+1}  \Rightarrow Z=\frac{w-1}{-w+1} $$

which implies that : $$X=\frac{2u-1-u^2-v^2}{(1-u)^2+v^2}$$
put $v=0$ and $$X<0 \Rightarrow u^2-2u+1 >0\Rightarrow(u-1)^2>0$$

So $E=\mathbb{C}\smallsetminus]-\infty,-1[ \cup]1  , \infty[$

Is that result true ?
Is there any other idea to get the result ?

Comment: $\tanh$ is an odd function, hence the image of a symmetric domain with respect to the origin has to be symmetric with respect to the origin.

Answer (score 0):

The function $g(z)=e^{2z}$ maps the open strip $-\frac{\pi}{2}<\text{Im}(z)<\frac{\pi}{2}$ into $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0)$.
The function $h(z)=\frac{z-1}{z+1}$ is a [real homography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform) mapping $(-\infty,0)\setminus\{-1\}$ into $(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,+\infty)$ in a bijective way. Additionally, it maps $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{-1\}$ into $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$ in a bijective way (its inverse function is $h^{-1}(z)=\frac{1+z}{1-z}$).
It follows that $h\circ g=\tanh$ maps the open strip $-\frac{\pi}{2}<\text{Im}(z)<\frac{\pi}{2}$ into $\color{red}{(\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R})\cup(-1,1)}$.